# C# Casting types from Interfaces

Tags: c#, class, interface, casting

I want to create a set of classes that are very similar and can be cast to each other types. My idea was that I would create an Interface object and implement it through a base class. Then create additional classes that inherit from my base. I could then use the Interface to work with the common (base) methods and cast an object from the BASE object to a custom type.

```
interface ImyInterface {

}

public class MyBase : ImyInterface {

}

public class MyCustom1 : MyBase {

}

public class MyCustom2 : MyBase {

}


// in helper class
public static MyBase GetGeneralOjbect() {

    // get a generic base object
    return new MyBase();
}

// How I'm trying to use this

MyCustom1 obj = GetGeneralOjbect() as MyCustom1;
```

This seems to work except for the casting of the object statement. MyCustom1 is always null even though the static helper GetGeneralOjbect returns a good MyBase object. Maybe this can't be done or I'm not doing it correctly. Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you can cast a `MyCustom1` or `MyCustom2` to `MyBase`, but not necessarily the other way.

When you create a `MyBase` via `MyBase b = new MyBase();`, `b` is a `MyBase` but not a `MyCustom2`, so casting `b` to `MyCustom2` will fail.

What you *can* do is:

```
MyBase b = new MyCustom2();
MyCustom2 c = b as MyCustom2();
```

What you *can't*  do is:

```
MyBase b = new MyCustom2();
MyCustom1 c = b as MyCustom1();
```

Comment: I suspected this was the case. Thought I would try it out for this particular situation I was doing but wasn't sure if it was correct. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Well...you *can* do it...it will just crash and burn at runtime. `MyCustom1 c = new MyCustom2();` won't even compile, even with an explicit cast.

Comment: Yes, you *can* do it, but as the OP noticed, the result of the second cast will be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can cast up an inheritance chain but not down it. Say you had the following class heirarchy:

```
public class A {
}

public class B : A {
}

public class C : B {
}
```

If you instantiated a new instance of type B you could cast it to A but not C.

Answer (score 1):

The "as" keyword says "if this object which is statically typed as MyBase has a runtime type of MyCustom1, then give it back to me statically typed as MyCustom1; otherwise, give me a null reference". The object you are casting has a runtime type of MyBase, not MyCustom1, which is why you are getting a null reference.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Factory Pattern?

Answer (score 0):

An instance of `MyCustom1` can be used whenever an instance of `MyBase` is expected, but `MyBase` cannot be used when `MyCustom1` is expected.